# Is Signal/Slot mechanism is faster than Queue mechanism?

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a Qt program that communicate with `specific digital board` with `LAN` and `Serial Port`, These packets should be read from LAN and send to other device connected to pc immediately. we have a problem with those packets come from serial port. we get these packets with emit on `readyRead Signal` and using `readAll` function for reading `QByteArray` inside the connected Slot. the problem is: delay on reading packets. I want to change the `signal/slot mechanism` to producer/costumer queue mechanism (using `mutex` for prevent `critical section`). Is `queue mechanism` faster than `signal/slot` or not?

Some code like below: this is not an executable function just present  in pseudocode

```
func1Thread() //customer thread
{
  while(!stopThread)
  {
    if(queueSize>0)
    {
       //parse packet
    } 
    else 
      msleep(100);
  }
}

func2Thread() //producer thread
{
  while(!stopThread)
  {
    if(!socket.waitForReadyRead())
    {
       qByteArray ba= socket.readAll();
       //enqueue here
    }
  }
}
```

thanks

Comment: I expect both solutions to be similar. You probably have to write code for both and benchmark in release mode.

Comment: Concerning socket communication... Are you aware of the [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) and how to disable it? I struggle to believe that the `readyRead` signal is your real performance problem. (So, I was thinking what it could be instead and remembered how we faced (and fixed) such an issue once.)

Comment: O.T., nit-picking: A mutex is not dedicated to _prevent critical section_. Instead, it is responsible to introduce / implement a critical section. Maybe, you are not aware that [**Critical section**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) has a specific and positive meaning concerning concurrency and is actually intended to remark portions of code where exclusive access to shared resources is (and must be) granted. ;-)

Comment: A queueing mechanism done correctly will be about the same as the queueing mechanism Qt already implements.  Done incorrectly (e.g. using `msleep(100)` instead of a condition variable for blocking when the queue is empty) it will be much, much slower.